# Не принимает пакет udp java

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, udp

Клиент:

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.*;

 public class Client {
 public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String message = new String();
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Вычисление значения функции");
    boolean flag = false;
        double x = new Double("0");
        double y = new Double("0");
        double z = new Double("0");
        String controlString = new String();
    while (flag != true) {
        System.out.println("Введите x:");
        controlString = bRead.readLine();
        try {
            x = Double.parseDouble(controlString);
            flag = true;
            message+=controlString;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Вы вводите строку!");
        }
    }
    flag = false;
    while (flag != true) {
        System.out.println("Введите y:");
        controlString = bRead.readLine();
        try {
            y = Double.parseDouble(controlString);
            flag = true;
            message+="/";
            message+=controlString;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Вы вводите строку!");
        }
    }
    flag = false;
    while (flag != true) {
        System.out.println("Введите z:");
        controlString = bRead.readLine();
        try {
            z = Double.parseDouble(controlString);
            flag = true;
            message+="/";
            message+=controlString;
            message+="/";
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Вы вводите строку!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Сформированное сообщение:"+message);
    byte[] data = message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length,address,3456);
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);

    DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1000], 1000);
    while (true) {
        datagramSocket.receive(pack);
        String serverMessage = new String(pack.getData());
        System.out.println("Сообщение от сервера:" + serverMessage);
        datagramSocket.close();
    }

}
}
```

Сервер:

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.net.DatagramPacket;
   import java.net.DatagramSocket;
   import java.net.InetAddress;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import static java.lang.Math.atan;
   import static java.lang.Math.sin;
   import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class Server {
public static ArrayList<String> arrayList;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(3456);
    String clientMessage;

        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1000], 1000);
        datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
        clientMessage = new String((datagramPacket.getData()));
        System.out.println("Получено от клиента:" + clientMessage);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        UntoString(clientMessage);

        double x = new Double(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)));
        double y = new Double(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(1)));
        double z = new Double(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2)));

        double F = new Double(0);
        double f1 = new Double( - sqrt(x));
        f1 = Math.pow(y,f1);
        double f2 = new Double((x-(y/2)));
        double f3 = new Double(f1*f2);
        double f4 = new Double(atan(z));
        f4 = sin(f4);
        f4 = Math.pow(f4,2);
        double f5 = new Double(x+y);
        f5 = Math.exp(f5);
        F = f3+f4+f5;
        System.out.println("Значение функции:" + F);
        String message = Double.toString(F);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Lb.txt");
        out.println(x);out.println(y);out.println(z);out.println(F);
        out.close();

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        byte[] data2 = message.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(data2,data2.length,address,3456);
        datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket2);
        System.out.println("Отправлено клиенту:" + message);
        datagramSocket.close();
}

public static void UntoString(String beginString)
{
    int flag = beginString.lastIndexOf("/");
    Function(beginString,0,flag);
}

public static int Function(String BeginString,int Index,int flagIndex)
{
    int tmp = Index; int middle_index = 0;
    middle_index = BeginString.indexOf("/", Index);
    String first = new String(BeginString.substring(tmp, middle_index));
    arrayList.add(first);
    if(middle_index != flagIndex) {
        return (Function(BeginString, (middle_index +1), flagIndex));
    }
    else{return 0;}

}
}
```

Клиент не принимает ответ от сервера

ИСПРАВЛЕННЫЙ:

```
       import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
       import java.net.*;

      public class Client {
      public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String message = new String();
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Вычисление значения функции");
    boolean flag = false;
        double x = new Double("0");
        double y = new Double("0");
        double z = new Double("0");
        String controlString = new String();
    while (flag != true) {
        System.out.println("Введите x:");
        controlString = bRead.readLine();
        try {
            x = Double.parseDouble(controlString);
            flag = true;
            message+=controlString;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Вы вводите строку!");
        }
    }
    flag = false;
    while (flag != true) {
        System.out.println("Введите y:");
        controlString = bRead.readLine();
        try {
            y = Double.parseDouble(controlString);
            flag = true;
            message+="/";
            message+=controlString;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Вы вводите строку!");
        }
    }
    flag = false;
    while (flag != true) {
        System.out.println("Введите z:");
        controlString = bRead.readLine();
        try {
            z = Double.parseDouble(controlString);
            flag = true;
            message+="/";
            message+=controlString;
            message+="/";
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Вы вводите строку!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Сформированное сообщение:"+message);
    byte[] data = message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length,address,3456);
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);

    datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    datagramPacket.setPort(3456);
    datagramPacket.setAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
    String received = new String(datagramPacket.getData(), 0, datagramPacket.getLength());
    System.out.println("Сообщение от сервера:" + received);
    datagramSocket.close();


}
}


         import java.io.IOException;
         import java.io.PrintWriter;
         import java.net.DatagramPacket;
         import java.net.DatagramSocket;
         import java.net.InetAddress;
         import java.util.ArrayList;

        import static java.lang.Math.atan;
        import static java.lang.Math.sin;
        import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

      public class Server {
      public static ArrayList<String> arrayList;

     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(3456);
    String clientMessage;

        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1000], 1000);
        datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
        clientMessage = new String((datagramPacket.getData()));
        System.out.println("Получено от клиента:" + clientMessage);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        UntoString(clientMessage);

        double x = new Double(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)));
        double y = new Double(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(1)));
        double z = new Double(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2)));

        double F = new Double(0);
        double f1 = new Double( - sqrt(x));
        f1 = Math.pow(y,f1);
        double f2 = new Double((x-(y/2)));
        double f3 = new Double(f1*f2);
        double f4 = new Double(atan(z));
        f4 = sin(f4);
        f4 = Math.pow(f4,2);
        double f5 = new Double(x+y);
        f5 = Math.exp(f5);
        F = f3+f4+f5;
        System.out.println("Значение функции:" + F);
        String message = Double.toString(F);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Lb.txt");
        out.println(x);out.println(y);out.println(z);out.println(F);
        out.close();


        byte[] data2 = message.getBytes();
        datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data2,data2.length);
        datagramPacket.setAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        InetAddress address = datagramPacket.getAddress();
        datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data2, data2.length, address,3456);
        datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
        System.out.println("Отправлено клиенту:" + message);
        datagramSocket.close();
}

public static void UntoString(String beginString)
{
    int flag = beginString.lastIndexOf("/");
    Function(beginString,0,flag);
}

public static int Function(String BeginString,int Index,int flagIndex)
{
    int tmp = Index; int middle_index = 0;
    middle_index = BeginString.indexOf("/", Index);
    String first = new String(BeginString.substring(tmp, middle_index));
    arrayList.add(first);
    if(middle_index != flagIndex) {
        return (Function(BeginString, (middle_index +1), flagIndex));
    }
    else{return 0;}

}
}
```

Comment: как вы думаете, на каком порту будет ожидать сообщений сокет, созданный конструктором `DatagramSocket()`?

Comment: На порту 3456 будет

Comment: Получается ни на каком, но если задать 3456, получится куча ошибок и клиент не передаст серверу строку

Comment: datagramSocket.connect(address,3456); Добавил, все равно не принимает

Comment: посмотрите [обучалку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html), особенно [код сервера](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/examples/QuoteServerThread.java). Обратите внимание, как создается ответный пакет.